# How can i get all values in a global set

Tags: plugin-development, globals

I would like to get all the fields (with their handles and values) for a given global set.

For example : My set is called 'labels'.
I know I can get the set by using :

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::GlobalSet);
$criteria->handle = 'labels';
$labels = $criteria->first();
```

Or with :

```
$labels = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('labels');
```

Then I can get a specific data with

```
$labels->myDataHandle
```

But how can I get all the data/fields in the set ?
I would like to have an array or an object with all my labels (in my controller I return the value using returnJson).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2928/125) given here to someone trying to solve this in the template. With a plugin you'd probably do it like so:

```
public function getFieldsByEntry($entryModel)
{
    $fields = array();
    $fieldLayoutFields = $entryModel->getFieldLayout()->getFields();
    foreach ($fieldLayoutFields as $fieldLayoutField)
    {
        $fields[] = craft()->fields->getFieldById($fieldLayoutField->fieldId);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```